# Regex: Ending with a specific thing

Tags: regex, bash, terminal

I am trying to find an expression that begins with Hello and ends in one of two ways: with nothing after the "Hello", or if it has something else after it needs to be preceded with "//". After the //, anything goes.

I tried: `grep '^Hello(//.*)?$'` but this does not work.
There is something wrong with the last part: `(//.*)?$`

```
Sample Input:
Hello
Hello blah
Hi
Hello //
Hello // blah blah
Hello //blah

Sample Output using egrep:
Hello
Hello //
Hello // blah blah
Hello //blah
```

Comment: best to include sample input and expected output. Include a sample input that is similar, but should not match. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter edited. Hopefully that clears it up.

Comment: How does something end with nothing? Do you mean white space?

Comment: @Yunnosch Sorry for the strange phrasing, essentially yes.

Comment: "Essentially". Explain please, read [ask] and [mcve]. Also please explain how it "does not work". And give more examples of what should be matched and what should not.

Comment: Should `Hello//blah` match?

Comment: Should `Hello // blah` match?

Comment: Should `Hello //blah blah` match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward with egrep:

```
egrep '^Hello(\s*\/\/.*)?$' input.txt
```

That is:

- `^ ...` - Force the match to start at the beginning of the line.
- `Hello` - Definitely match the required phrase `Hello`.
- `(\s* ... )` - Allow optional whitespace to follow `Hello`.
- `( ... \/\/ ... )` - Match the forward slashes, escaping them (because some shells can do funny things to your regexes).
- `( ... .*)` - Allow anything after the slashes.
- `( ... )?` - The question mark indicates the parenthesized part is optional.
- `... $` - Force the regex to only match if it consumes through the end of the line.

You were using `grep` instead of `egrep`.  Plain `grep` uses a much simpler regex syntax that doesn't allow some of the operators you might like to use.  Notably, in plain `grep`, parentheses and `?` are just plain characters, not special meta-characters for grouping, so plain grep was searching for *literal* `(` and `)` in your file.  When in doubt, prefer `egrep`.

(And yes, for the pedantic folks in the audience, `egrep` is indeed just an alternate name for `grep -E` or `grep --extended-regexp`, but it's much easier to remember and type `egrep` than either of the other two "native" forms.)

Comment: Note: This will match `Hello //` with nothing after the `//` since `.*` at the end means 0 or more of whatever.

Comment: Her sample output (now) includes `Hello //` as part of the expected result, so I think that's the behavior she wants.

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
$ echo "$txt" 
Hello
Hello blah
Hi
Hello //
Hello // blah blah
Hello //blah
```

With `grep`:

```
$ echo "$txt" | grep -E '^Hello$|^Hello[[:space:]]+//'
Hello
Hello //
Hello // blah blah
Hello //blah
```

Or with `awk`:

```
$ echo "$txt" | awk '/^Hello$/ || /Hello[[:space:]]+\/\//'
Hello
Hello //
Hello // blah blah
Hello //blah
```

Or if you want to make sure there is something after the `//`:

```
$ grep -E '^Hello$|^Hello[[:space:]]+//[^[:space:]]+'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the "match only whole lines" option of egrep (`-x`).
Then look for optional whitespace (`[[:space:]]*`), two escaped `/` (`\/\/`) followed by anything or nothing, `.*`.
Use the optional specifier and parenthesis to allow the special ending, not require it (`(...)?`).

```
egrep -x "Hello([[:space:]]*\/\/.*)?"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another awk proposal. The first part /^Hello$/ matches just a singel Hello and the second part matches // and in this case prints the entire line.

```
awk '/^Hello$/||/\/\//' file

Hello
Hello //
Hello // blah blah
Hello //blah
```